# Can I use Expo's XDE without having to log in via the internet?

Tags: macos, react-native, authentication, ide, expo

I don't have internet access where I live. I prefer to do my programming research at a library then do my coding at home without the internet to distract me.

But now I'm interested in React Native and it seems that I can't use XDE if I haven't logged in to the internet?

Or am I missing something?

I'm using MacOS Sierra on a MacBook Air connected via USB to a new Android phone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your USB connect your PC and run this command

```
react-native run-android
```

if you can't run or it can't find android. You need to eject it before

```
react-native eject
```

actually follow the offical website https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies

Comment: So first it told me `Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli` which I did, then `Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?` and eject told me `App `name` must be defined in the `app.json` config file to define the project name. It must not contain any spaces or dashes.` and `react-native android` told me `Unrecognized command 'android'`

Comment: ok did you try `react-native eject` then `react-native run-android` again

Comment: Yes and eject told me `App name must be defined in the app.json config file to define the project name. It must not contain any spaces or dashes.` so I tried adding one and then got a complaint about some other missing field ... App `displayName` must be defined in the `app.json` config file, to define the label of the app on the home screen. I thought this might just keep coming up with more missing fields so I didn't pursue that path ...

Comment: OK I now added both fields and so far it's very busy trying to do stuff (-: ... The second terminal it spawned got an error: `React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph...2017-08-18 14:32 node[3644] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
2017-08-18 14:32 node[3644] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
2017-08-18 14:32 node[3644] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
 ERROR  Error wa ...

Comment: Main terminal ran for a while then died with `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

Comment: I think you should follow with the official website. I thought you had all android stuff. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies

Comment: No I started with Expo & XDE, and I'm working from that point to get around its insistence that I log in via the Internet before I work on my code that's all local.

Comment: yes you can if you had all dependencies. you can `react-native run-android` then you can work locally